# How to find median degree over all vertices in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know that with Cypher, it is possible to write a query to find the median of a given property (using `PERCENTILE_DISC` or `PERCENTILE_CONT`). However, I would like to write a query that calculates the median of a collection of values that isn't coming from a property. Something like:

```
MATCH u:User-->r:Review
WITH u, count(r) as edges
RETURN median(edges)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you actually tried that? Using percentile_disc(edges, 0.5) seems to work on http://console.neo4j.org/

Comment: Haha, that's embarrassing. I seem to recall trying this before and having it throw an error because it couldn't find a `.` after `edges`, but I must've been mistaken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:Review]->()
WITH u, count(r) as edges
RETURN percentileDisc(edges, 0.5)
```

A more efficient solution, as suggested by [inversefalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92359/inversefalcon), would be

```
MATCH (u:User)
WITH u, size((u)-[:REVIEW]->()) as edges
RETURN percentileDisc(edges, 0.5)
```

Comment: This does work, but you might want to favor using `size()` on the pattern to get the degree info from the :User nodes without paying the cost of actually expanding to the other side: `MATCH (u:User) WITH u, size((u)-[:REVIEW]->()) as edges RETURN percentileDisc(edges, 0.5)`